# Google sheets sumproduct sumif multiple criteria that does not contain certain keywords summed per keyword and not once for all

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, formulas, sumifs

I have a sheet that sums certain expenses based on multiple criteria

For example utilities are summed in a following way

`=SUMPRODUCT(sumif(A:A,{"*water*","*intern*","*rent*"},C:C))`

I have sums like that for many different expenses, now issue is I am trying to have a sum of "other expenses", where I would add everything that is NOT the keywords that I have used previously... I have tried using negation in following manner

`=SUMPRODUCT(sumif(A:A,{"<>*Vanduo*","<>*int*","<>*nuoma*"},C:C))` (list of excluded values here isn't full it's just an example)

What I got is everything added for each keyword every time, what I mean is my total expenses were around 11k but what I got after using formula above is ~33k, which implies that it added everything for each keyword every time...

**How to do a `sumif sumproduct` (or some other way) that would exclude keywords, but would do it only once and not per keyword?**

**P.S** I have already solved this problem by having a `sum` of everything in `C` column and then subtracting all the `sumproduct sumifs` that I have, however I would like to compare this value to value with negated keywords to check for errors.

Comment: Note that if you use `=SUMPRODUCT(sumif(A:A,{"*water*","*intern*","*rent*"},C:C))` it's possible to sum the same row twice if the column A text contains more than one of the keywords

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you are using is `OR`, You want `AND`

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"<>*Vanduo*",A:A,"<>*int*",A:A,"<>*nuoma*")
```